# How can I run multiple instances of OpenVPN?

Tags: networking, openvpn

I want to run multiple OpenVPN client instances on the same machine. Ideally, I want to have an OpenVPN client for each user in the system, so each one of them will communicate to internet through the logical network interface `tunX` that is created from openVPN clients.

1. How can I run multiple instances, one for each user? Should I start OpenVPN using `sudo openvpn --config config1.ovpn` or `sudo systemctl start openvpn`?
2. How can I make traffic for each user go through the appropriate `tunX` interface?

The answer to first question is solved. I will use `sudo systemctl start openvpn@0001` for instantiating an OpenVPN client that uses configuration `/etc/openvpn/0001.ovpn` and so on for other users (0002.ovpn, 0003.ovpn, ...).

But the second problem remains. For example: two users, each executes one openvpn client, but the first one only can communicate to internet using his `tun0` interface IP. The other one uses the `tun1` IP gets error `connect ETIMEDOUT` when trying to do a request to the internet.

Comment: And do you have unique IP adresses *for each user*? ("so each one can have unique IP address." is not the way this works. You need unique IP adresses per user not the other way round).

Comment: @Rinzwind Machine has one IP, but I thought that each user via openvpn will get his own using vpn

Comment: This is how to do it on PORTs. https://www.hugeserver.com/kb/openvpn-multiple-ports/#comment-841 In the questions section there is one about different external IP adresses.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thank you for the article link. What I do not understand is that in the article it says I have to setup an OpenVPN server. I only use the OpenVPN as client to connect to paid OpenVPN servers using the `.ovpn` configuration files. Do I have to run also an OpenVPN server on the same machine?